# Find all possible ordered triples for the system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

Suppose that r, s, and t are nonnegative integers which satisfy the system:
$$rs+ t = 14$$
$$r + st = 13$$

Find all possible ordered triples $$ (r,s,t) $$which satisfy these conditions.

What I tried:
I got r and t in terms of s.
$$s = (14-t)/r$$
$$s = (13-r)/t$$

After this is where i'm stuck. Do I substitute the S equations into each of the systems respectively? I tried substituting each S equation into it's system equation and I got 13 = 13, and 14 = 14.

$$r + t(13-r)/t = 13$$
$$13 = 13$$

$$r(14-t)/r + t = 14$$
$$14 = 14$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}1&=14-13\\&=rs+t-r-st\\&=s(r-t)-(r-t)\\&=(s-1)(r-t).\end{align}Since we are dealing with integers here, there are not many possibilities. You will have to have $s=2$ and $r=t+1$ or $s=0$ and $r=t-1$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: How did you get 1 = 14 - 13?

Comment: @ViciCIT Well, I'd say that the *definition* of $14$ is $13+1$.

Comment: ohh. I understand how you got to (s-1)(r-t) =1, because you subtracted the two systems of equations. However, now i'm confused after how you started talking about the possibilities and s=2. EDIT: I see now that you set (s-1) and (r-t) equal to 1.

Comment: I substituted r = t+1 and s=2 into rs + t = 14, and I got t = 4.

Comment: Now I substituted t = 4 and s = 2 into r+st = 13. r = 5. Are these all my possible ordered triplets, t=4 s=2 and r= 5?

Comment: The full list of solutions is $(r,s,t)=(5,2,4)$ and $(r,s,t)=(13,0,14)$.